# Laplace Operator of Norm is Dirac Distribution?

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show that:
$\Delta f = c \delta_0$
where $f(x) = \frac{1}{||x||_2^a}$ and $\delta_0$ is the $n$-dimensional Dirac distribution.
$n$ is a natural number and I want to find $a(n)$ so that the above equation is true.

I tried calculating out the Laplace operator of $f$ and I get a lovely function, but I have no idea how to get that to be a Dirac distribution, in fact I think that entire way if going about it is probably wrong. Anyone have any tips or ideas?

Comment: What is $a$?${}$

Comment: Sorry, $a$ is an element out of the real numbers.

Comment: No need to apologize at all. I somehow missed the $c$ in front of your $\delta_0$ and confused myself.

Comment: First I would suggest writing the laplacian in spherical coordinates. Then the easy part is showing that, for $r\neq 0$ $\Delta f=0$ for a certain $a$ which is related to $n$